# Dynamically importing Python module

Tags: python, dynamic-import

I have a trusted remote server that stores many custom Python modules. I can fetch them via HTTP (e.g. using `urllib2.urlopen`) as text/plain, but I cannot save the fetched module code to the local hard disk. How can I import the code as a fully operable Python module, including its global variables and imports?
I suppose I have to use some combination of `exec` and `imp` module's functions, but I've been unable to make it work yet.

Comment: are you downloading them over ssl or is every intermediate router trusted as well? :P

Comment: Actually, yes - both the module storage and the front-end server are parts of a single system (and are even located in the same server room). For now, suppose there are no security implications: even if I download the code over SSL, the question of how to interpret it still stands.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It looks like this should do the trick: [importing a dynamically generated module](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/82234-importing-a-dynamically-generated-module/)

```
>>> import imp
>>> foo = imp.new_module("foo")
>>> foo_code = """
... class Foo:
...     pass
... """
>>> exec foo_code in foo.__dict__
>>> foo.Foo.__module__
'foo'
>>>
```

Also, as suggested in the ActiveState article, you might want to add your new module to `sys.modules`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules["foo"] = foo
>>> from foo import Foo
<class 'Foo' …>
>>>
```

Comment: Is there a trick so that I could allow the user to "from foo import Foo"?  In this example, I get "ImportError: No module named foo".

Comment: After `sys.modules["foo"] = foo`, the `sys` module breaks and equals `None`. Is that supposed to happen or can you avoid that? See my question on that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37498894/creating-alias-of-module-in-sys-modules-causes-sys-to-become-none).

Comment: @DavidWolever It seems that `imp.new_module` is deprecated since Python 3.4 ([ref](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/imp.html#imp.new_module)). Use [`importlib.util.module_from_spec`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.module_from_spec) instead.

Answer (score 5):

Here's something I bookmarked a while back that covers something similar:

- [Customizing the Python Import System](http://blog.dowski.com/2008/07/31/customizing-the-python-import-system/)

It's a bit beyond what you want, but the basic idea is there.

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered trying to do this while trying to write unit tests for source code examples I put into a project's readme (I wanted to avoid just linking to small files or duplicating the text in a way that could get out of sync).

I came up with the following

```
import sys
import types
from importlib import import_module


def compile_and_install_module(module_name: str, source_code: str) -> types.ModuleType:
    """Compile source code and install it as a module.

    End result is that `import <module_name>` and `from <module_name> import ...` should work.
    """
    module = types.ModuleType(module_name, "Module created from source code")

    # Execute source in context of empty/fake module
    exec(source_code, module.__dict__)

    # Insert fake module into sys.modules. It's now a real module
    sys.modules[module_name] = module

    # Imports should work now
    return import_module(module_name)
```

And a quick example of how you can use it

```
$ cat hello.py 
def foo():
    print("Hello world")


bar = 42

$ python
Python 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from compile import compile_and_install_module
>>> compile_and_install_module("hello", open("hello.py").read())
<module 'hello'>
>>> import hello
>>> hello.foo()
Hello world
>>> from hello import bar
>>> bar
42
```

You can remove the return value and import_lib import if you

Comment: The `types.ModuleType` seems to be the new way of creating modules dynamically, since `imp` is deprecated now. +1 to you.

Answer (score 0):

Python3 version 
(attempted to edit other answer but the edit que is full)

```py
import imp

my_dynamic_module = imp.new_module("my_dynamic_module")
exec("""
class Foo:
    pass
""", my_dynamic_module.__dict__)

Foo = my_dynamic_module.Foo
foo_object = Foo()

# register it on sys
import sys
sys.modules[my_dynamic_module.__name__] = my_dynamic_module
```