# Importing module from network

Tags: python, networking, module, import, centralized

Is there a way to get python to read modules from a network?

We have many machines and it would be a too much effort to update each machine manually each time I change a module so I want python to get the modules from a location on the network.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically importing Python module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799545/dynamically-importing-python-module)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mount your network location into your file-system and add that path to your PYTHONPATH. That way, Python on your local machine will be able to see the modules which are present in the remote location.
You **cannot** directly import from modules remotely, like specifying a js file in html.

Comment: What do you mean 'like specifying a js file in html'..  like a <script> tag?

Comment: @ryanmonk  in HTML you can import modules even though  they are not present in project folder. you import it from internet as follows.       <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    but python does not allow  it.

Answer (score 2):

How I ended up doing this:

Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System >> Advanced >> Environment Variables >> System Variables >> New >> Name = PYTHONPATH, value = \server\scriptFolder

Thanks everyone for all the help :)

Answer (score 2):

```
sys.path.append(r'\\network\path')
import module
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be notable that a module for importing packages/modules available through HTTP/S exists and it is [`httpimport`](https://github.com/operatorequals/httpimport). This is for both Python2 and Python3.

So, as of the accepted answer, it turns out that there are ways to programmatically import remote modules "like javascript" as follows:

```py
>>> with httpimport.remote_repo(['package1'], 'http://my-codes.example.com/python_packages'):
...     import package1
...
>>> # -- 'package1' code is available here --
```

---

**Edit (31/01/2023):**
The syntax of most `httpimport` commands has changed after the `1.0.0` re-write. The new parameters for `remote_repo` omits the first argument, as below:

```py
>>> with httpimport.remote_repo('http://my-codes.example.com/python_packages'):
...     import package1
...
```

You might want to look at all usage examples provided in the repository README:
https://github.com/operatorequals/httpimport#basic-usage

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for a distributed computing framework, where you deploy code and data to one node and they are distributed as task among a cluster of clients/servers/peers. Check [Pyro](http://www.xs4all.nl/~irmen/pyro3/), [execnet](http://codespeak.net/execnet/), [Parallel Python](http://www.parallelpython.com/), [Jug](http://luispedro.org/software/jug) and [RPyC](http://rpyc.wikidot.com/).

Answer (score 0):

While it's a little pathological to want to import modules over the network, it *is actually possible*. Take a look at [the source for `zipimport`](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Modules/zipimport.c) to get an idea of how it can be done.

Comment: Could you comment in a few words why this is not a good idea? Is this a disponibility concern or something more related to the core language?

Comment: Security and speed reasons. If your network is compromised (or if you're doing something even crazier such as importing over the *Internet*) then you risk losing the server. And if you run the script multiple times per second then you will have that much more traffic over the network.