# How do you read in a text (.txt) file as a .py file in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, module

I have a shared folder that contains a text file that I want my program to reference as though it were a .py file. For example, my .txt file has a dictionary in it that I reference in my program. How do i import the dictionary from a text file? Do i read it in line by line? Or is there a way to trick python into thinking it is a .py file.

Here is a sample similar to my .txt file:

```
#There are some comments here and there

#lists of lists
equipment = [['equip1','hw','1122','3344'],['equip2','hp','1133','7777'],['equip3','ht','3333','2745']]

#dictionaries
carts = {'001':'Rev23', '002':'Rev11','003':'Rev7'}

#regular lists
stations = ("1", "2", "3", "4", "11", "Other")
```

Comment: related: [Dynamically importing Python module](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3799545/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like what you need is a [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) file.

Example: consider you have a `source.txt` with the following contents:

```
{"hello": "world"}
```

Then, in your python script, you can load the JSON data structure into the python dictionary by using [json.load()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load):

```
import json 

with open('source.txt', 'rb') as f:
    print json.load(f)
```

prints:

```
{u'hello': u'world'}
```

---

You can also use [exec()](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement), but I don't really recommend it. Here's an example just for educational purposes:

`source.txt`:

```
d = {"hello": "world"}
```

your script:

```
with open('test.txt', 'rb') as f:
    exec(f)
    print d
```

prints:

```
{'hello': 'world'}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Are .json files easy to edit? I want this file to be easily edited.

Comment: I have multiple dictionaries and lists in this reference file. Will they all be usable via this method?

Comment: @Cole is there a python code inside? could you show a sample contents?

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer. I edited in an example.

Comment: @Cole well, the easiest option would be to convert the file to `.py` and import it. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python.

Comment: @Cole yeah, you should really trust the source if you'd go with this option.

Comment: i tried that, but i can't figure out how to import the .py file from a shared network folder. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: @Cole there are options, check if any of the answers from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710588/importing-module-from-network help.

Answer (score 3):

If you completely trust the source `.txt` file, check out [execfile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=execfile#execfile).