# Import module from network instead of local

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, python-module

We are working on writing some modules and centralizing them on our local network.

As suggested here: [Import from network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710588/importing-module-from-network)

I altered my PYTHONPATH to point to the network location.

Problem is that when I run the python shell, import and do: `print my_mod.__file__` it's still pointing to my local directory.

Is there any way to import from the network location instead of locally, but keeping both links so I can work on the local?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There can be various things that make it not do what you expect, for instance:

- Setting `PYTHONPATH` does not make it search there *first*, python will still look in your current directory before anywhere else.
- Having the particular module installed in your local `site-packages` as well can cause it to be imported from there first if it uses a `.pth` file or some other import trickery.
- Make sure you don't have any `.pyc` files in your local directory that are picked up for what you're importing.

You can check the paths that are searched in order by issuing `import sys; print(sys.path)` in your python shell.

The solution is perhaps to put your network location manually as first element in `sys.path`:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/network/modules/location")
import thing_you_want
```