# Running code on import from dynamically generated module

Tags: python

I have used [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3799609/2085701) to dynamically generate a module `x` and register it in `sys.modules`. I want a piece of code to run automatically when an import is called on this module. so for example I want `print "you just imported module x"`. So it behaves like:

```
>>> import x
you just imported module x
```

How do I get this behavior?

Comment: why not put it in the module itself? i.e right before `class Foo:` in the example

Comment: Should this happen every time the module is imported? If so, you'll probably need to mess with import hooks to do that.

Comment: Padraic that doesn't give the desired behavior because the print code is executed when `exec` is called not when the module is imported.

Answer (score 0):

To simply extend the example given in the selected answer you could something like this.

```
print "You just imported module {}".format(foo.Foo.__module__)
```

Comment: If you do that and then run the line from the example `exec foo_code in foo.__dict__` the print will happen as soon as you call `exec` this does not make it so the print runs on `import foo`

Comment: That would be true if that was in the module being imported. My understand is this code would go in the module doing the importing.

Answer (score 0):

Any "orphan" code (code that isn't written inside a class or a function, or inside an `if __name__ == '__main__:'` block) will be executed when you import the module.