# Dynamically creating module in sys.modules causes sys to become None

Tags: python

I'm creating a module called `Qt` ([Github link](https://github.com/mottosso/Qt/blob/master/Qt.py)) where I alias another module (for example `PyQt4`), so that when I import `Qt` I am in fact importing `PyQt4`:

```
from Qt import QtWidgets  # this really imports PyQt4.QtGui
```

Example `Qt` module:

```
# Qt.py
import sys
import PyQt4.Qt

sys.modules["Qt"] = PyQt4
PyQt4.QtWidgets = PyQt4.QtGui
```

However, If I add `print sys` at the end of Qt.py, `sys` equals `None`:

```
print sys
>>> None
```

Why does `sys` "break" and can I avoid breaking it?

This is in Python 2.7.11 on OS X.

---

@Lol4t0 – Here's an example where I'm only using standard modules:

```
# Xyz.py

import os
import sys

sys.modules['Xyz'] = os
print sys  # this will print "None"
```

So importing this will result in that "None is printed:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Jan 22 2016, 08:29:18)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Xyz
None
```

Comment: Is this behaviour observed only for PyQt modules?

Comment: @Lol4t0 no, this also happens with e.g. `PySide`.

Comment: Then can you make an example, that only use standard modules, that shows the problem, so everyone can run it on their machine and was able to investigate?

Comment: @Lol4t0 ok, added an example "Xyz.py".

Comment: Thanks. I see, you can just reimport sys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When there are no longer any reference to a module, it will drop all its globals by replacing them with `None`.

You need to remember the *old* verion of `sys.modules['Xyz']` (i.e. the current module) until you are done executing it.

Comment: Aha, I see now. This happens not only to `sys`... but it actually happens to *any* imported module inside the python file. By changing the filename to not match the module I register, this issue doesn't happen.