# How to import a module in Python 3 from a string?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

A [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799545/dynamically-importing-python-module) for this problem is available for Python 2, but it uses the `imp` module which is deprecated in Python 3.

`imp` has been replaced by [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) which works well for file based imports. Specifically, `importlib.import_module` requires a file name - not a string or a file handler.

I made a workaround by dumping the contents of the URL to a file and importing it

```
def initlog():
    modulename = '_mylogging'
    try:
        import _mylogging
    except ImportError:
        r = requests.get('http://(...)/mylogging.py')
        with open(modulename+'.py', "w") as f:
            f.write(r.text)
    finally:
        import _mylogging

    return _mylogging.MYLogging().getlogger()
```

but I would like to avoid the intermediate file.

Putting the security, network performance and availability issues aside - **is there a way to feed a string to `importlib`?** (or from a file handler, in which case I would use [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adapt [exactly the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3799609/3001761) to 3.x, using [the replacement for `imp.new_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.ModuleType):

```
from types import ModuleType

foo = ModuleType('foo')
```

and [the replacement for the `exec` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec):

```
foo_code = """
class Foo:
    pass
"""

exec(foo_code, globals(), foo.__dict__)
```

After which everything works as expected:

```
>>> dir(foo)
['Foo', '__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__']
>>> foo.Foo()
<__main__.Foo object at 0x110546ba8>
```

Comment: Very good, thanks!

Comment: But, the recipe didn't work for me until I changed


<pre><code>
exec(foo_code, foo.__dict__, foo.__dict__)
</code></pre>