# Python extension modules package structure (namespaces)

Tags: python, c++

I am writing Python extension modules for my C++ application. Also, I embedded Python interpreter in the same application and use these modules. So, I am not building separately these extension modules, because modules are created and used in the same application (just add `PyImport_AppendInittab("modulename", &PyInit_modulename)` before the `Py_Initialize()`). 
If I do it like this is it possible to create Python package structure?
Currently, I have `import module`, but I need to have the possibility to use `import package.module` in my embedded Python interpreter.
Is there anything for creating packages like there is a function for modules `PyModule_Create()`?

Comment: You can try to build module dynamically like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799545/dynamically-importing-python-module

Comment: No, it does not help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My further research shows that it is not possible to have packages structure in extension modules. Actually, you can create the structure using a simple trick, add a module to existing module as an object. For example, you can create the structure like this: `mod1.mod2.mod3`. But, it's not same like packages. You cannot use `import mod1.mod2` or `import mod1.mod2.mod3`. You have to use import mod1, and that will import all modules. No way to import just one module.