# dynamic import of dynamically created modules fails

Tags: python

background:

- a daemon creates package p1 (e.g. directory with `__init__.py` file)
- then in p1 a module m1 is created.
- then the daemon wants to import from m1, which functions (so far all the time).
- Then a module m2 is created in p1 and the daemon wants to import from m2 which fails (most of the time but *not* always) with ModuleNotFoundError.

See the little test script at the end which reproduces the problem.

The very strange thing for me is, that the import of m2 in the test script sometimes works.  I wonder if there is some package-content-caching.  And if so how to prevent or re-trigger it.

(neither a reload of p1 nor a deletion of p1 from sys.modules does the trick)

```
"""
(python --version: Python 3.8.2)
Dynamic import of dynamically created modules right after creation.
"""

from shutil import rmtree
from os import path, chdir, mkdir, listdir
from importlib import import_module, reload
import sys

# for test-package creation
P1 = 'p1'
INIT = '__init__.py'
INIT_CONTENT = """\
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""

# for first test-module creation
M1 = 'm1'
M1_CONTENT = """\
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

answer = 42
"""

# for second test-module creation
M2 = 'm2'
M2_CONTENT = """\
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

hello = 'world'
"""

chdir(path.dirname(__file__))    # make sure we are in the right directory

if path.isdir(P1):
    rmtree(P1)                   # always start off under the same conditions


mkdir(P1)                        # create test-package and first test-module
with open(path.join(P1, INIT), 'w') as f:
    f.write(INIT_CONTENT)
with open(path.join(P1, M1+'.py'), 'w') as f:
    f.write(M1_CONTENT)

# import from the just created module; this worked always so far
from p1.m1 import answer

print(f'{answer=}')

with open(path.join(P1, M2+'.py'), 'w') as f:
    f.write(M2_CONTENT)          # create the second test-module

# check current directory, file and module structure
print('wd-content:', ', '.join(listdir()))
print('p1-content:', ', '.join(listdir(P1)))
print('p1-modlues:', ', '.join([m for m in sys.modules if m.startswith(P1)]))
# reload(sys.modules[P1])  # neither a reload
# del sys.modules[P1]      # nor a deletion of p1 does the trick

# here it most of the time fails (but NOT all the time)
# so far if it fails it fails in all three variants
# so far if it works the 'from ...'-import works already
try:
    from p1.m2 import hello
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    try:
        hello = getattr(import_module(f'{P1}.{M2}'), 'hello')
    except ModuleNotFoundError:
        try:
            hello = getattr(__import__(f'{P1}.{M2}', fromlist=[None]), 'hello')
        except ModuleNotFoundError:
            raise
        else:
            print("__import__-import worked")
    else:
        print("import_module-import worked")
else:
    print("'from ... '-import worked")

print(f'{hello=}')
```

Comment: Speculation: it sounds like a race condition. When you import p1, only m1 exists. If m2 is created quickly enough, then the global module name table is not finished updating, and m2 is there. Otherwise, it has already imported the module, and [the module is imported only once per interpreter session](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html). See if the note above par 6.1.1 helps: re-import the module. See also [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3799545/dynamically-importing-python-module)

Comment: Thanks. I don't get your point.  m2 is not changed as stated in 6.1.1 but it is created and it is not in sys.modules, e.g. it can't be reloaded.  A reload of the package p1 containing m2 has no effect as mentioned in my question.

Comment: After creating `m2`, what does `print(dir(p1))` states?

Comment: print(dir(sys.modules[P1]))
` ['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'm1']`

funny enough this is the output of a successful run of the script. I added your line after 'print('p1-modlues ...'

Answer (score 0):

As I thought :) removing the entry for 'p1' from 'sys.path_importer_cache' seems to solve the problem.